# PHP cURL to SSL page not working (IEXtrading API)

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I'm trying to create PHP code that uses the IEXtrading API to obtain stock information.  That API accepts GET requests to a HTTPS URL and returns stock data. I've put together a simple PHP cURL request, as shown below, to try and get the price of GOOGL stock:

```
$url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/googl/price";

$ch = curl_init();

$user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:8.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
echo $result;

//$error = curl_error($ch); 
//echo "<hr><br>$error";

curl_close ($ch);
```

For some reason, though, what I'm getting in response is a site maintenance page, that says the following:

```
We’ll be back soon!

Sorry for the inconvenience but we’re performing some maintenance at the     moment. Check Twitter for up to date information. If you need to you can always     email us or call us at 646.343.2000, otherwise we’ll be back online shortly!

— The IEX Team
```

It seems like I'm doing something wrong, since I can manually go to that URL (https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/stock/googl/price) and it returns the correct price information.  I'd appreciate any insight into what I might be doing wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, just try again ... i copied your exact code and got the expected output: `1025.07`

Comment: I also copied your code verbatim and it works. The remote site might be blocking you with some kind of flood control after too many requests or something? Or perhaps they were actually taking the site down? Hard to say.

Comment: I spoke with the tech support for IEXtrading.com and he said that "The php/curl library needs to support SNI for it to successfully connect."  I'm not quite sure what that means, but apparently that's the problem.  Any thoughts on how to fix that issue?